# Validating UTF32->ASCII

Tags: vb.net, text, ascii

I'm making a program that draws text from a spreadsheet and then pastes it into a .txt file. The problem I've found is that if the character isn't a valid ASCII one it's replaced by characters ranging from ? to ^ or superscript numbers.

I know this is because these characters aren't ASCII supported, but how could I check and swap them out? Is there a list of non-ascii supported characters I can use, or a function that checks validity?

Thanks

Comment: It could be that your text editor is not using the encoding which was used to write the file. .NET will write files using UTF-8 if you don't tell it to do otherwise.

Comment: No, that's fine, I've specifically used ASCIIEncoding() to add the text to the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its' more the other way around. there is no such thing like ASCII support. What you could do is give your textfile a UTF32-BOM first, then your texteditor can interpret the numbers it reads and has the possibility to show the right characters.
see wikipedia "Byte Order Mark".

Edit after discussion:
if you only need 7-bit ASCII and nothing else, use either Encoding.ASCII or Andrews approach.
otherwise you could use ASCIIEncoding.GetEncoding(yourcodepage)

```
Dim thisText As String = "ÄÖÜäöü" & " Pi: " & ChrW(&H3A0) & " Sigma: " & ChrW(&H3A3) 
Dim fileOut As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Dim enc_ascii As System.Text.Encoding
enc_ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII '7-bit
Using output As New StreamWriter(New FileStream(fileOut & "\test1.txt", FileMode.Create), enc_ascii)
    output.Write(thisText)
End Using
enc_ascii = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetEncoding(1250) 'central europe
Using output As New StreamWriter(New FileStream(fileOut & "\test2.txt", FileMode.Create), enc_ascii)
    output.Write(thisText)
End Using
enc_ascii = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetEncoding(1253) 'greek
Using output As New StreamWriter(New FileStream(fileOut & "\test3.txt", FileMode.Create), enc_ascii)
    output.Write(thisText)
End Using
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not up to me to create/ edit the text editor- if it was I'd be using UTF32.

Comment: hmm . . . if I understand right, so there will be only one special text editor possible that does not support unicode?

Comment: Yeah, It's a text file for another application, and the app only uses ASCII-supported characters.

Comment: OK. just one thought, people sometimes confuse ANSI and ASCII, so make sure that what you need is really 7-bit ASCII, and nothing else.

Comment: Ooh, the `enc_ascii = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetEncoding(1253)` did exactly what I was looking for- that's something for me to fiddle around with, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

ASCII characters have values from 0 to 127, so you could use the [AscW function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
If AscW(inputChar) > 127 then
    outputChar = "*"c
Else
    outputChar = inputChar
End If
' now write outputChar
```

Comment: @Andrew_Morton thanks, that seems like the best approach (short of creating a list of banned characters). One question though, what does `outputChar = "*"c` do?

Comment: @niallmcfc It's just a substitute for the unsupported characters. A space or question mark might be more appropriate for you, use whatever you need to.